# How can I embed Django REST API documentation on the Angular landing page?

Tags: django, angular, typescript, django-rest-framework, swagger

Any ideas how can I embed Django Swagger Documentation or built-in documentation on the Angular frontend? I mean by clicking documentation button on the landing page the user will be routed to the swagger documentation in the area of the same domain. At the moment I can redirect the user for instance from `frontenddomain` to `backenddomain/doc` but it may be bothersome because new tab will be opened in the web browser. Maybe you could recommend other solution than Swagger? I just to want display the user all the endpoints of the api in my landing page. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I know how to do routing to the another component etc. I just wonder how can I embed documentation in one of these components? Or maybe there is any other better solution? At the moment I can do for instance like show below. But as you can see it redirects the user to another domain. I would prefer something like this `[routerLink]="['/cloud']"` and I the `/cloud` I would have my Swagger documentation. If any additional information is required just let me know. I hope that you will understand what I want to achieve.

```
</li>
        <li class = 'nav-item' *ngIf="!isDocumentation() && !sidebarVisible && !isWelcome()">
          <p class='sidebar-false-documentation' *ngIf="isCloud()">
          <a href="http://localhost:8000/doc" class="nav-link" target="_blank"><i
            class="nc-icon nc-book-bookmark"></i>Documentation</a>
          </p>
        </li>
```

Comment: can you share how your urls.py looks like and the code you're using to link the button?

Comment: @RudolfOlah I updated the question. Any ideas?

Comment: one option is to use URL rewriting with NGINX or Apache or whatever your web server is and to have the `/frontend/docs` rewritten as `/backend/docs`. You could also use an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new component and route in your Angular app, link to that route.

Put nothing in that component except an iFrame that loads your documentation page.